# Get logs of smart contract (EVM)

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, evm

I need to get all events of my smart contract to be able to show change history of an object.

Ti do that, I use the following code that I found on documentation.

```js
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
provider
          .getLogs({
            fromBlock: "earliest",
            toBlock: "latest",
            address: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTRACT_ADDR,
            topic: actifContract.interface.events.ActifUpdated,
          })
          .then((res) => console.log(res));
```

I use "ethersjs" lib to interact with the BC.
My problem is that I can't get any event even if I'm sure some event, of type "ActifUpdated" were raise.
How can I get the expected result ?

I use BC for this project to be able to trace any change of my objects.

Comment: `topic` should be `topics`

Comment: @Yilmaz thanks, unfortunatly it doesn't fix the problem.